# Get Current Price of Product

Tags: ms-access

Good Day all, 
I need help with my expression. I am trying to place it in a text box in my Form. When the Product (sUPC) is selected the most recent price is automatically filled based on the current date. I have a Prices Table (Prices) that stores the current price of the product. EFFDATE is the date when the price will be applied. UPC is the ProductID on the prices table and sUPC is the combo box on my form.

```
    DLookUp("Price","Prices","sUPC=UPC" And
    Format(Now(),"dd/mm/yyyy")=DMax("[EFFDATE]","Prices",
   "[EFFDATE]<=#" & Format(Now(),"dd/mm/yyyy") & "#"))
```

After selecting the Product the text box remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it too complicated:

```
DLookUp("[Price]", "[Prices]", "sUPC = 'UPC' And [EFFDATE] = DMax('[EFFDATE]', '[Prices]', '[EFFDATE] <= Date()')")
```

For a specific date:

```
DLookUp("[Price]", "[Prices]", "sUPC = 'UPC' And [EFFDATE] = #" & Format(SomeOtherDateValue, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```

or a mix of these:

```
DLookUp("[Price]", "[Prices]", "sUPC = 'UPC' And [EFFDATE] = DMax('[EFFDATE]', '[Prices]', '[EFFDATE] <= #' & Format(SomeOtherDateValue, 'yyyy\/mm\/dd') & '#')")
```

Comment: So the expression is only returning the price for 1 Product and that Product have 3 prices with different EFFDATE: 1/12/18 - $3.00, 1/1/19 - $4.00 and 2/2/19 - $5.00. Based on the current date, it is returning $5.00 correctly but the other products have 1 date history (1/1/19). When I select those products the text box remains blank.

Comment: Then you can look up the price for that date. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Now the text box remains blank. What I am trying to achieve is: -
Product 1 - EFFDATE 2/2/19 - $5.00
Product 2 - EFFDATE 1/1/19 - $3.00
Product 3 - EFFDATE 1/1/19 - $2.50
Product 3 - EFFDATE 1/3/19 - $3.50
Using Today's Date (26/2/19) how to return the most recent price? 
Product 1 - $5.00
Product 2 - $3.00
Product 3 - $2.50

Comment: Then combine the two examples - replace Date() in the first with the formatted string expression for the date value in the second.

Comment: Still not working but I came up with
`=DMax('Price','[Prices]','[EFFDATE] <= Date() AND UPC=sUPC')`. What do you think?

Comment: ....but it returning $3.50 for Product 3. It should only return $3.50 on or after 1/3/19. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same results as my first comment.

Comment: Then you have no `EFFDATE` earlier than the value of `SomeOtherDateValue`.

Comment: I got it to work. 
`DLookUp("[Price]","[Prices]","sUPC =UPC And [EFFDATE] = DMax('[EFFDATE]', '[Prices]', 'sUPC=UPC And [EFFDATE] <= #' & Format(Date(), 'dd\/mm\/yyyy') & '#')")` **sUPC=UPC** was missing from the EFFDATE criteria

Comment: That is probably pure luck. `sUPC=UPC` should read `sUPC='UPC'` except if UPC is another field. And the format in `<= #' & Format(Date(), 'dd\/mm\/yyyy') & '#` is wrong and, if right, should be replaced with `<=Date()`.

Comment: UPC is a field in my form. I had to remove the ' for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`DLookUp("[Price]","[Prices]","sUPC =UPC And [EFFDATE] = DMax('[EFFDATE]', '[Prices]', 'sUPC=UPC And [EFFDATE] <= #' & Format(Date(), 'dd\/mm\/yyyy') & '#')")` sUPC=UPC was missing from the EFFDATE criteria –